# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' - Laravel - I don't have a 0 column anywhere in my code

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm getting this weird error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: update `forum_threads` set `0` = locked, `1` = 1, `updated_at` = 2016-03-17 16:01:59 where `topic_id` = 3 and `forum_threads`.`deleted_at` is null)

The thing is, I don't have a 0 column. I don't have a where clause with a `0` anywhere in my code. I am using a scope query.

My controller is:

```
    $action = $request->input('action');
    $topic = $request->input('topic');
    $thread = Thread::where('topic_id', $topic);

    switch ($action) {
        case ('locked'):
            $thread->lock();
            break;
    }
```

As you can see, I don't do much. I am just trying to lock a thread. I am calling the lock scope in my `Thread` model. I have a lot of switch cases, one of which is `lock`. I have run half of the query at the top so I don't have to repeat myself. I simply stored it in the `$thread` variable so that I can perform actions like `$thread->delete()` and `$thread->restore()`.

My query scope in Thread model:

```
public function scopeLock($query)
{
    return $query->where('locked', 0)->update(['locked', 1]);
}
```

That's it. I think it may because I have a where clause passing from my controller (`Thread::where('topic_id', $topic)`) and I'm just continuing it onto my scope.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `$thread = Thread::where('topic_id', $topic)->first();` Complete this query and try?

Comment: Also, `->update(['locked' => 1]);`

Comment: Still getting the same error. And I have many threads, not just one that I will be editing so that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The error is due to  `->update(['locked', 1]);` which should be `->update(['locked' => 1]);`

the update function uses an array as "column" => "value", your syntax error causes Laravel to think `[ 0 => 'locked', 1 => 1]`, so it translates to this SQL `SET 0 = 'locked', 1 = 1`...

Comment: Haha, I figured it out just before coming back to post an answer. You were the first to answer so I'll accept your answer. Thank you!

Comment: @TaylorSwift I answered this in the comment section. :/

Comment: Same thing can occur when youre trying to use a factory create.

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in the comment section, change your function to this:

```
public function scopeLock($query)
{
    return $query->where('locked', 0)->update(['locked' => 1]);
}
```

Note the changes in the update method.

Answer (score 2):

I had a double condition in WHERE

```
ContestPool::where(['contest_id', '=', $contest_id], ['user_id', '=', $user_id])->delete();
```

I fixed adding brackets for both conditions

```
ContestPool::where([['contest_id', '=', $contest_id], ['user_id', '=', $user_id]])->delete();
```

Answer (score -2):

in my case the problem was in the model attributes.I use protected $fillable, protect $foreignKey, protected $timestamp. to solve de problem, I put all the attributes in protect $fillable variable.