# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' where clause

Tags: sql, laravel, model, controller

Hi I have a problem in laravel that has something to do with my database.

this is my LoginController:

```
        class LoginController extends Controller
{
    function index()
    {
        return view('login');
    }

    function checklogin(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ],
            ['name.required' => 'Gebruikersnaam is niet ingevuld of niet goed.', 'password.required' => 'Wachtwoord is niet ingevuld of niet goed.']);

        $user_data = array([
            'name' => $request->get('name'),
            'password' => $request->get('password')
        ]);


        if (Auth::attempt($user_data)) {
            return redirect('login/succeslogin');

        } else {
            return back()->with('error', 'Verkeerde login gegevens!');
        }

    }

    function succeslogin()
    {
        return view('succeslogin');
    }

    function logout()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('login');
    }

}
```

This is my Login model:

```
    class Login extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

This is the SQLSTATE error:
[sqlerror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ic6iG.png)

This is what happends when I do:

```
dd($user_data);     
$user_data = array([
            'name' => $request->get('name'),
            'password' => $request->get('password')
        ]);
```

[dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vToA.png)

So I tried a few things here and there but nothing worked so far.
Seems like it is making an extra array somewhere but I cant find it..
Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: "Seems like it is making an extra array somewhere but I can't find it." `array([])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrapping your credentials array in an extra array. Remove the extra array wrap:

```
$user_data = [
    'name' => $request->get('name'),
    'password' => $request->get('password')
];
```

Comment: Thanks at least it does something now, I do get another error.. it now says  Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of App\Login given, called in C:\laragon\www\SDE2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard.php

Comment: what ever model you use for Authentication must implement the `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` interface ... check the default User model to see

Comment: Would you please stop undoing my close votes. This is a clear duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36065951/column-not-found-1054-unknown-column-0-in-field-list-laravel-i-dont-ha